# android update project –path "command not found"

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to develop an app using OCR that runs on Android. I am following the steps in

http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/

I have passed the “ndk-build” step and advanced to the “android update project –path .” step . But it shows "android: command not found error". I am new to android development. Can anyone please tell me how do I set path variables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which OS you are using it wont work in ubuntu 11.10. did you download android-ndkr7?

Comment: Learning how to set a `PATH` environment variable is not really a programming question. Use a search engine to find out how to do that for whatever OS you are using for development. You will want to add the `tools` and `platform-tools` directories from your SDK to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 7):

Edit to Festus's answer:

***don't do this:*** `export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools`. this will change the entire PATH variable.

Instead use the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

This should add the path for tools and platform-tools to the existing PATH.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using mac or Linux OS

Assuming that you have set ANDROID_HOME to point to the sdk install:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/android-sdks
```

Add Tools to PATH

```
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
```

Add platform-tools to PATH

```
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using this command ---> android update project -p

use this command

android.bat update project -p  {project path }

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered same problem in Windows. I did it this way and it works for me .

```
 $ $ANDROID_SDK/sdk/tools/android.bat update project -p .
 Updated local.properties
 Updated file C:\ndk\android-ndk-r9b\samples\hello-jni\proguard-project.txt
 It seems that there are sub-projects. If you want to update them
 please use the --subprojects parameter
```

Here first used "cd" command to go the ndk project directory that is way I used "."(dot) for path(-p)

$ANDROID_SDK/sdk/tools/android.bat update project -p .